# Xtext grammar error "cannot find type for [State]" is thrown even if there is such a type

Tags: dsl, xtext

I have this grammar:

```
StateMachine:
    declarations+=Declaration*;

Declaration:
    Transition |
    State;

Transition returns Declaration:
     "trans" label=ID ":" source=[State] "->" target=[State] ";" ;

State returns Declaration:
     "state" id=ID ";" ;

@Override
terminal WS: 
    (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r')+;

@Override
terminal ID: 
    ( 'a' .. 'z'  |  'A' .. 'Z' ) ( 'a' .. 'z'  |  'A' .. 'Z'  |  '0' .. '9' )* ;
```

In Transition rule when I'm trying to use ref to State type error "cannot find type for [State]" is always thrown. When I use it without [], so not as a cross reference everything works fine. How could I solve this situation ? What could be wrong with this grammar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
"trans" label=ID ":" source=[State] "->" target=[State] ";" ;
```

In Xtext `[Foo]` means "a crossreference to an instance of type `Foo`". Is does NOT mean "a reference to a grammar rule". Xtext does NOT generate a `State` type because of this line:

```
State returns Declaration:
```

where `returns Declaration` means "The rule `State` will return a type `Declaration`" and hence no type `State` is necessary.

The following grammar will fix it:

```
StateMachine:
    declarations+=Declaration*;

Declaration:
    Transition |
    State;

Transition:
     "trans" label=ID ":" source=[State] "->" target=[State] ";" ;

State:
     "state" id=ID ";" ;
```

Here Xtext will generate types for `Declaration`, `Transition` and `State` where `Transition` and `State` derive from `Declaration`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One more question: would it be the same fix if I change only State grammar rule like this: 
`State returns Declaration:
  {State}"state" id=ID ";" ;`
Seems like it works also, but I want to know if there is any difference between your fix and mine, or if I could use any of them, as it's basically the same.

Comment: both solutions are legit and the inferred metamodel is the same in this case. in others it might be not

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ChristianDietrich !